# Reasons to discourage "here" links in web pages

Tags: seo, usability, hyperlink

I know that using "here" for a link's text is considered bad, but if I want to persuade business- or architect-type people, what are the best arguments to use? I know it can have some effect on Search Engine Optimization (SEO), but can anyone explain this and any other reasons in more detail?

An example:

> The StackOverflow site can be found
>   [here](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the text gives the link no context. Semantically, you're saying that the url goes "here" which means nothing. Screen readers, search engines, or anything else that parses the page cannot tell where (semantically) the page goes, so it knows nothing about the destination aside from its url.

Comment: You are correct, but you leave out that people generally *click more often* when you use the word 'Here.' See for example: http://dustincurtis.com/you_should_follow_me_on_twitter.html

Comment: @Eli But with scanning users, and a study less specific than the one you cite, at what rate are those users finding the information they *intended*?

Comment: @Eli: Interesting link, but a) It's still up for debate as to whether it was the wording or the length that made a difference and b) There's no doubt that the wording of a sentence containing a link can affect the CTR, but the article does *not* compare "To visit _stack overflow click here_" vs "To visit stack overflow _click here_" (ie same wording, but linking a different part of the text with better semantics.

Answer (score 4):

One reason is that using "here" links are bad **from an accessibility point of view** - often screen readers (like JAWS, etc.) have functionality that will pick out all links in a page - if they are not meaningfully named, the user is in a useless situation.

Answer (score 3):

Since links are highligted (often underlined and a different color) using links that explains what they link to makes it a lot easier to scan a web page.

Jacob Nielsen has written a lot of articles about how people read web pages: [Alertbox: Current Issues in Web Usability](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/). The executive summary is that people do not read web pages like they read books. They scan for information and then read if they find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142393/reasons-to-discourage-here-links-in-web-pages#1142402) is the answer.

I bet you thought twice before hitting that link

It's pretty clear from here which one is better

> Visit the [Stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) site

or

> Click [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com) to visit the
>   Stackoverflow site

The confusion (if you want to call it that) arises when you are *actually* trying to get the user the click on something, eg. click here for more information, but even in those cases it is better to not use the click here format.

Answer (score 2):

Page on which you are placing the link, no one will search with the word "here".

The text inside the link makes huge impact on the list of search results.
Do you want to see your site higher in search results? Do you want to find information in the search engines faster? So do not use "here"-links, they does not help users and search engines.

The main rule of placing the links: **first write the text, then add links**.

The same applies to "more"-links in news excerpts.

Answer (score 1):

'Click here', or simply 'here', often results in a smaller clickable area than a full description of link. This is annoying when if it is difficult for you to point on the link, like when surfing with an iPhone.

(I personally hate those web pages where the link to the second page of an article is just a minuscule '2' at the bottom, and there is no big 'next page' button.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've just explained it yourself.

It may also have usability issues. Naturally, you would want to click on the object's name. If it's a text, you will have to spend time scanning the whole sentence watching out for underlined or differently colored words. In the latter case it's real bad and against the common usability guidelines to have links stand out from the rest of the text. With the example like yours, it will result in reduced readability of pages especially with some amount of links and consequently in lower productivity of the users.